# Docker in Win (Linux containers): docker-compose command fails somehow outside of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I am testing Docker containers, and I managed to create an image, using Visual Studio and Docker Compose, that seems to be OK:

Images:

[image]

The image is a .NET Core Console application, very small and simple. It does connect to a Redis server and starts producing some stuff, and logs this to console. This is how it looks if I start the project directly from Visual Studio (no Docker involved):

[image]

Now, if I run it via Visual Studio, by setting the "docker-compose" project to Startup, and then pressing the play button on top, that says "Docker Compose", I can see that this command is executed:

> docker-compose -f "C:\Git\alfa\AlfaModulesPoc\docker-compose.yml" -f
> "C:\Git\alfa\AlfaModulesPoc\docker-compose.override.yml" -f
> "C:\Git\alfa\AlfaModulesPoc\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml"
> -p dockercompose5247976386926556655 --no-ansi up -d

I now see the Output in VS display the console correctly:

[image]

also Docker Desktop shows it:

[image]

**But**, if I run the same command from the command line:

[image]

I can see that Docker thinks it is running:

[image]

and I then take a look at Docker Desktop, there are no logs being captured any more:

[image]

And, the logs are not shown, because it seems that there is no activity at all from the container. I would see data being created in the Redis database, but when started manually from the command prompt, then no data is touched on Redis.

- Why isn't the container running properly?
- Can I see any errors, exceptions or something to determine what is going on?

Comment: The very last -d command according to the documentation of docker-compose up --help states it runs in detached mode.   Try running without the -d and it should show you the console output in the same window you are using instead of just saying ... done.  Maybe this will give you some more clues.  Also I have found that [Portainer](https://www.portainer.io/) makes it very easy to manage docker and see what is going on, It cleared up a lot of my questions why something is not working.

Comment: Thanks. Removind the `-d` option does indeed show me the console, but it freezes on "Attaching to AlfaCom". I will take a look at Portainer! =)

Comment: I would also try to look at the extra compose.yaml files and see what they are doing.  According to [compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) passing multiples in like that will cascade down values and overwrite configuration.  My gut thought is maybe it has to do with the path you are running docker-compose from, maybe those other yaml files are referencing a relative path that does not match when you run it outside of VS code, just a guess.  Good Luck!

Comment: Yes, I read that too about the cascading. I dont think the path can be wrong, I am executing the commands from the same folder as VS is, I think, and also specifying the same file, copied the command exactly. Very odd... Thanks! =)

Comment: Portainer seems not-so-easy to install, are you on windows?

Comment: Try using "--build" option with docker compose .

Comment: @Ted I am on windows and I just followed the [directions](https://www.portainer.io/installation/) here.  It setup everything up and I just browsed to localhost:9000 to see everything.

Comment: @Ted there is also a --verbose flag you can pass to docker compose that might give you more clues.

Comment: @pavinan --build option didnt change anything