# Docker in Win (Linux container): Docker Compose in Visual Studio uses hidden .yml file

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

In testing Docker, I used Visual Studio to containerize one project in a solution. Folder structure like this:

```
/AlfaModulesPoc.sln
/Modules/AlfaCom/AlaCom.csproj
/Modules/AlfaCom/Dockerfile
```

I did this by right-clicking the project --> Add... --> Docker Support... and choose "Linux":

[image]

VS then created the Dockerfile, that looked good on paper, but in reality could not be used since the paths in that Dockerfile was based on the Dockerfile being placed in the solution folder (2 folders "up"), but it was placed inside the project folder (as I expected).

Building the image from here did not work at all, files could not be found etc.

The workaround was to also add "Container Orchestrator Support..." which created a new project called "docker-compose" in the solution root folder, and a `docker-compose.yml` file that looks like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  alfacom:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}alfacom
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Modules/AlfaCom/Dockerfile
```

As soon as I added this Orchestration Support, VS also proceeded in creating the image automatically and starting it. At this point, I did not pay attention to the Output logs.

When checking Visual Studio Output window, I was the expected console logs that the program gives out, and I also saw data being handled in the Redis server, since the program adds data to Redis. I also looked in the Docker Desktop application, and saw the same console logs. Looked good to me.

I then stopped it, and tried to start it manually, via console, like this:

```
PS C:\Git\alfa\AlfaModulesPoc> docker-compose -f "C:\Git\alfa\AlfaModulesPoc\docker-compose.yml" -p dockercompose5247976386926556655 --no-ansi up -d
```

but that failed with the error:

> Step 6/20 : COPY
> ["../Submodules/Core/CoreCommons/CoreCommons/CoreCommons.csproj",
> "../Submodules/Core/CoreCommons/CoreCommons/"] Service 'alfacom'
> failed to build: COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build
> context: ../Submodules/Core/CoreCommons/CoreCommons/CoreCommons.csproj
> ()

- **Question 1:** Why? I am using the .yml file, and that files says that `context: .` so why this error?

And its not until I realize that VS actually had 3 different yml files. The command VS executed was:

```
PS C:\Git\alfa\AlfaModulesPoc> docker-compose -f "C:\Git\alfa\AlfaModulesPoc\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\Git\alfa\AlfaModulesPoc\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "C:\Git\alfa\AlfaModulesPoc\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose5247976386926556655 --no-ansi up -d
```

and it is the very hidden, auto-generated file `docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml` that contains the most settings:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  alfacom:
    image: alfacom:dev
    container_name: AlfaCom
    build:
      target: base
      labels:
        com.microsoft.created-by: "visual-studio"
        com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name: "AlfaCom"
    environment:
      - NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=
    volumes:
      - C:\Git\alfa\AlfaModulesPoc\Modules\AlfaCom:/app
      - C:\Users\wagge\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw
      - C:\Users\wagge\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/packages:ro
    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
    labels:
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.program: "dotnet"
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.arguments: " --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/packages  \"/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/AlfaCom.dll\""
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.workingdirectory: "/app"
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.killprogram: "/bin/sh -c \"if PID=$$(pidof dotnet); then kill $$PID; fi\""
    tty: true
```

Running the same 3-yml-command that VS did removes the error:

[image]

- **Question 2**: What is it in this .yml file that fixes it? is it the `C:\Git\alfa\AlfaModulesPoc\Modules\AlfaCom:/app` line under `volumes:`?

So, the container is now running, but [not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62676590/docker-in-win-linux-containers-docker-compose-command-fails-somehow-outside-o).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any yml files that visual studio uses "behind the scenes" should be ignored it seems.

The problem is using project references, if those exits outside of your solution directory, you need to have NuGet references instead

Comment: A better solution that NuGets: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62849278/178143